# CSS shape something like tea drop

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create this shape ( on the uploaded image ) only with css borders but I have problem with the corners they are not accepting the right shape. May I ask you guys for advice or best practice how to create it ?

[image]

Here is my code

```css
.tea-drop {
  width: 90px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tea-drop"></div>
```

Comment: Should be exactly like the image ?  or you need a tea drop ?

Comment: CSS is not meant for drawing pretty pictures. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. Use SVG.

Comment: it should be something like the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SVG` is the recommended way to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale-ability.

We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create a shape like above and fill it with some solid color, gradient or a pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Following code will create above shape:

```
<path d="M 0,0
         C 100,10 120,150 60,75
         Z" />
```

Below is a brief description of `path` commands used in above code:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `Z` command is used to close current path. It draws a straight line from current point to the starting point to close the shape.

**Output Image:**

[image: Tea Drop Shape]

**Working Example:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(teal, skyblue);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M0,0
           C 100,10 120,150 60,75
           Z" />
</svg>
```

---

This shape can be filled with gradient or pattern as well. `<linearGradient>` element is used to define a gradient in `SVG`. This element can then be referenced later using an `id` attribute to fill or outline any shape.

```
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="orange" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="green" />
</linearGradient>
```

The direction of the gradient is controlled by the `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` while `<stop>` elements are used to define colors and their position along the gradient line.

**Output Image:**

[image: Tea drop shape filled with gradient]

**Working Example:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(teal, skyblue);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="orange" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,0
           C 100,10 120,150 60,75
           Z" fill="url('#grad')" />
</svg>
```

---

We can even apply shadow to this shape using `SVG`'s filters. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Filters_Tutorial) article on MDN explains the basics of filters.

**Output Image:**

[image: Tea drop shape filled with gradient and having a shadow]

**Working Example:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(teal, skyblue);
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="orange" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path d="M10,10
           C 110,20 130,160 70,85
           Z" fill="url('#grad')" filter="url('#shadow')" />
</svg>
```

---

**Useful Resources:**

Below are some useful links for SVG:

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 to make that.

```css
.tear {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80% 0 55% 50% / 55% 0 80% 50%;
  border-radius: 80% 0 55% 50% / 55% 0 80% 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(42.5447924299deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-45.26deg)  translateY(1px) ;
  transform: rotateX(42.5447924299deg) rotateY(100deg) rotateZ(-45.26deg)  translateY(1px) ;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear"></div>
```

Reference: http://enjoycss.com/SfB

I saved the link, you can customized it for yourself.